# Reading certificates crash/hang server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, x509certificate

In a .net 4.7.2 asp.net application we rely on certificates for communicating with our login provider, and working with files on GoogleDrive using the .Net SDK. 
However a few times every working day(higher load than on weekends) the site becomes unresponsive, this lasts for about 8-10 minutes. Creating a dump and analyzing it shows a lot of threads having the same stack trace.

The webservers experiencing this problem runs Windows Server 2008R2, and Windows Server 2012.

Hope someone can help me working out what causes the slow interaction with certificates.

Stacktrace #1 with 289 threads sharing the same stack trace

```
ntdll!ZwCreateFile+a 
rsaenh!CreateSystemDirectory+106 
rsaenh!CreateNestedDirectories+1fd 
rsaenh!GetUserStorageArea+2b5 
rsaenh!ReadContainerInfo+139 
rsaenh!OpenUserKeyGroup+3e 
rsaenh!NTagLogonUser+3fa 
rsaenh!CPAcquireContext+1f6 
cryptsp!CryptAcquireContextA+bef 
cryptsp!CryptAcquireContextW+ce 
advapi32!CryptAcquireContextWStub+11 
clr!CryptoHelper::WszCryptAcquireContext_SO_TOLERANT+78 
clr!COMCryptography::OpenCSP+1d4 
clr!COMCryptography::_OpenCSP+167 
[[HelperMethodFrame_2OBJ] (System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._OpenCSP)] System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._OpenCSP(System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters, UInt32, System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandleByRef) 
mscorlib_ni!System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters, Boolean)+52 
mscorlib_ni!System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(System.Security.Cryptography.CspAlgorithmType, System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters, Boolean, Int32, System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle ByRef, System.Security.Cryptography.SafeKeyHandle ByRef)+5d 
mscorlib_ni!System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()+87 
mscorlib_ni!System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32, System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters, Boolean)+c7 
System_ni!System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()+e3 
dk.nita.saml20.protocol.Saml20SignonHandler.TransferClient(dk.nita.saml20.config.IDPEndPoint, dk.nita.saml20.Saml20AuthnRequest, System.Web.HttpContext)+324 
dk.nita.saml20.protocol.Saml20SignonHandler.SendRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)+1c7 
dk.nita.saml20.protocol.Saml20AbstractEndpointHandler.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)+39
```

Stacktrace #2 with 106 threads sharing the same stacktrace

```
[[HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ] (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob)] System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[], IntPtr, UInt32, Boolean, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.SafeCertContextHandleByRef) 
mscorlib_ni!System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[], System.Object, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags)+e1 
System_ni!System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[], System.String, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags)+8a 
UvMedia.FileSharing.GoogleDrive.GoogleDriveServiceFactory.CreateAppsService(UvMedia.FileSharing.ProviderUser, UvMedia.FileSharing.GoogleDrive.GoogleAppsCustomerSettings, UvMedia.FileSharing.GoogleDrive.IGoogleAppsEmailMapper, UvMedia.FileSharing.Logging.ClientInfo, System.Func`1)+db 
UvMedia.FileSharing.GoogleDrive.GoogleDriveFileSharingService..ctor(UvMedia.FileSharing.GoogleDrive.GoogleAppsCustomerSettings, UvMedia.FileSharing.ProviderUser, System.String, System.String, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService, UvMedia.FileSharing.GoogleDrive.IGoogleAppsEmailMapper)+106 
UvMedia.FileSharing.GoogleDrive.GoogleDriveFileSharingService+d__17.MoveNext()+18e
```

Here is the code that loads the certificate in example #1. On the X509Certificate2 object that is returned only PrivateKey is used, however the X509Certificate2 object is never disposed in the code that calls GetCertificate()

```
public X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
        {            
            var store = new X509Store( storeName, storeLocation);
            try
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var found = store.Certificates.Find(x509FindType, findValue, validOnly);
                if (found.Count == 0)
                {
                    var msg = $"A configured certificate could not be found in the certificate store. {SearchDescriptor()}";
                    throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(msg);
                }
                if (found.Count > 1)
                {
                    var msg = $"Found more than one certificate in the certificate store. Make sure you don't have duplicate certificates installed. {SearchDescriptor()}";
                    throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(msg);
                }
                return found[0];
            }
            finally
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: it would be nice if you would show a problematic code part. What I can suspect (not sure for 100% without code) is memory leak by undisposed cryptography objects.

Comment: @Crypt32 Thanks for the answer, I think you might be on to something, I have updated my question with the code that loads the X509Certificate2, the certificate that is returned from the method is disposed.

Comment: And what about private key? Is it disposed after use? Disposing the certificate object doesn't dispose private key object. The stack you provide gives me a deja vu effect: https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/931908. This is a bit different issue, but lines for `rsaenh` and `ntdll` are very similar to issue described in KB.

Comment: The private key object is never disposed. Could this be solved by putting the used X509Certificate2 in a static variable and reusing the object? Or is the class not thread safe?

Comment: Cryptography functions (used by .NET behind the scene) generally are NOT thread safe. You don't need to use static field. You can dispose the key right along with disposing certificate. Or dispose it right after use. Then ensure you don't access the key instance twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it out, and mark the question as answered when i see the result :)